# adb command device name if %DEVICE%==

Tags: batch-file

im looking for the right way to use first name of the Device

i use

```
 for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb getdevice') do set DEVICE=%%a
echo Device      :    %DEVICE%
```

the output of Device is

```
 Nokia_fg514d
```

i want to use only the first name "Nokia_" Without "cd21ds"
in the next command
example :

```
 if %DEVICE%==Nokia_ (goto Nokia)
 if %DEVICE%==Sony_ (goto sony)
```

any help or suggestion ?

note : The script is not only for Nokia, is For multiple device brands the output of the device name command it will be like this ( sony_df1f , Nokia_Qsdf samsung_142dfd)

Comment: You can replace all `Nokia_`s with something else in the variable (`%DEVICE:Nokia_=x%`), and see if it's different from the original.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is to run the script only if the substring `Nokia` is within the results from `adb getdevice`, then what about, the following as your first line: ```@adb getdevice | find /i "nokia" >nul || exit /b```. If the case insensitive string `nokia` is not in the output, the script will end.

Comment: The script is not only for Nokia, is
For multiple devices and brands 
the output of the device command it will be like this ( sony_df1f , Nokia_Qsdf samsung_142dfd)

Comment: Use `for /F "delims=_" %%a...` which should set `device` to `sony`, `Nokia`, `samsung`. Or you could, instead of setting `device`, use `do for %%y in (nokia sony samsung) if /i "%%a"=="%%y" goto %%y` which would goto one of the labels or continue to the next line if the portion reported by `adb` before the first `_` is anything else.

Comment: yes perfect it works  `for /F "delims=_"`   post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for /F "delims=_" %%a...
```

which should set device to sony, Nokia, samsung.

Or you could, instead of setting device, use

```
 ...do for %%y in (nokia sony samsung) if /i "%%a"=="%%y" goto %%y
```

which would goto one of the labels or continue to the next line if the portion reported by adb before the first `_` is anything else.